# How to insert data into Parquet table in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, parquet

I have simple text table (delimited by ",") with the following format:

```sql
orderID INT, CustID INT, OrderTotal FLOAT, OrderNumItems INT, OrderDesc STRING
```

I want to insert this data into a Parquet table:
I've created the table using:

```sql
CREATE TABLE parquet_test (orderID INT, CustID INT, OrderTotal FLOAT, 
OrderNumItems INT, OrderDesc STRING) 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'parquet.hive.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe' stored as 
INPUTFORMAT 'parquet.hive.DeprecatedParquetInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 'parquet.hive.DeprecatedParquetOutputFormat';
```

but when I’m trying to insert the data using

```sql
insert overwrite table parquet_small_orders select * from small_orders;
```

it fails. any thoughts?

Answer (score 5):

I will share what I just tested and it is working perfectly fine. I know it might be a version related problem which Hive could've solved at this time. I will explain what I just did anyways,

**1. Checking raw data**

> $ cat myFile.txt

```
orderID INT, CustID INT, OrderTotal FLOAT, OrderNumItems INT, OrderDesc STRING
100,1000,100000,5,"aa"
200,2000,200000,6,"bb"
300,3000,300000,7,"cc"
400,4000,400000,8,"dd"
500,5000,500000,9,"ee"
```

**2. Mounting a Hive table pointing to the File**

```
Create external table myDB.orders(orderID INT, CustID INT, OrderTotal FLOAT, OrderNumItems INT, OrderDesc STRING)
row format 
delimited FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
STORED AS TEXTFILE 
LOCATION '/my/path/to/csv'
tblproperties ("skip.header.line.count"="1");
```

**4. Checking Hive table works correctly. Note that I added a sentence to ignore the first line, which is often is the header of the csv file.**

> select * from myDB.orders;

```
100,1000,100000.0,5,"aa" 
200,2000,200000.0,6,"bb" 
300,3000,300000.0,7,"cc" 
400,4000,400000.0,8,"dd" 
500,5000,500000.0,9,"ee"
```

**5. Mounting Parquet table:**

```
CREATE TABLE myDB.parquet_test (orderID INT, CustID INT, OrderTotal FLOAT,
OrderNumItems INT, OrderDesc STRING)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'parquet.hive.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe' stored as
INPUTFORMAT 'parquet.hive.DeprecatedParquetInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'parquet.hive.DeprecatedParquetOutputFormat'
location '/my/path/to/parquet';
```

**6. Inserting data from CSV Hive table to Hive Parquet table (Converting to parquet in the process)**

```
insert overwrite table myDB.parquet_test select * from myDB.orders;
```

Finally,  I double checked the data transformation was correct doing a simple query to `myDB.parquet_test`.
To be 100% sure the data is in Parquet, I went to `/my/path/to/parquet` and I double checked that those files are actually in Parquet. 
Not sure if your problem is because you are not skipping maybe the header of the file or maybe the version you are using, but again, these steps I just explained works well.

Answer (score 0):

What are the error messages that you get on hive server side?

I had a similar problem. In the hive server log I saw some heap memory problems.

I could solve the problem on my hadoop installation using higher values in mapred-site.xml

```
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.map.memory.mb</name>
  <value>1536</value> 
</property>

<property>
  <name>mapreduce.map.java.opts</name>
  <value>-Xmx1024M</value> 
</property>

<property>
  <name>mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb</name>
  <value>3072</value> 
</property>

<property>
  <name>mapreduce.reduce.java.opts</name>
  <value>-Xmx2560M</value> 
</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed these steps?

1. Download `parquet-hive-bundle-1.5.0.jar`
2. Revise `hive-site.xml` to include this:

   ```
   <property>
      <name>hive.jar.directory</name>
      <value>/home/hduser/hive/lib/parquet-hive-bundle-1.5.0.jar</value>
      <description>
          This is the location hive in tez mode will look for to find a site wide installed hive instance. If not set, the directory under hive.user.install.directory corresponding to current user name will be used.
      </description>
   </property>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Works for me; see below. 
We cannot see your csv table definition, but i believe that you may need to give it the delimiter?
Anyway, my code should help.

Matt

```
hive> create table te3 (x int, y int)                                        
    > row format delimited                                                   
    > FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','       
    > STORED AS TEXTFILE;
hive> LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/home/cloudera/test/' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE te3;
Copying data from file:/home/cloudera/test
Copying file: file:/home/cloudera/test/testfile.csv
Loading data to table default.te3
Table default.te3 stats: [numFiles=1, numRows=0, totalSize=12, rawDataSize=0]
OK
Time taken: 1.377 seconds
hive> select * from te3;                                                     
OK
1   2
3   4
5   6
Time taken: 0.566 seconds, Fetched: 3 row(s)
hive> create table ptest (a INT, b INT)
    > ROW FORMAT SERDE 'parquet.hive.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe' stored as 
    > INPUTFORMAT 'parquet.hive.DeprecatedParquetInputFormat' 
    > OUTPUTFORMAT 'parquet.hive.DeprecatedParquetOutputFormat';
OK
Time taken: 0.413 seconds
hive> insert overwrite table ptest select * from te3;
Total jobs = 3
Launching Job 1 out of 3
Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 since there's no reduce operator
Starting Job = job_1423179894648_0001, Tracking URL = http://quickstart.cloudera:8088/proxy/application_1423179894648_0001/
Kill Command = /usr/lib/hadoop/bin/hadoop job  -kill job_1423179894648_0001
Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 1; number of reducers: 0
2015-02-09 14:08:16,308 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2015-02-09 14:08:45,342 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 1.55 sec
MapReduce Total cumulative CPU time: 1 seconds 550 msec
Ended Job = job_1423179894648_0001
Stage-Stage-1: Map: 1   Cumulative CPU: 1.99 sec   HDFS Read: 234 HDFS Write: 377 SUCCESS
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 1 seconds 990 msec
OK
Time taken: 68.96 seconds
hive> select * from ptest;
OK
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
1   2
3   4
5   6
Time taken: 0.06 seconds, Fetched: 3 row(s)
hive>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Matthieu Lieber describes how you can load data to a parquet table.

Couple of things before you post your next question.

1. Please mention what version you are using. Parquet was not natively supported in Hive versions prior to 0.13 and you need to add some explicit jars to get the functionality.
2. Please add the logs/error messages. "It fails" is a vague description of the error and it makes things difficult to debug. The way you are doing the data load seems OK and it should work. However, a log would have made things clear as to what the issue is.

If this is still an open issue, you may refer to [Cloudera's documentation](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/core/latest/topics/cdh_ig_parquet.html) to see some basics as to how you can use Parquet with Hive.

Thanks!